# Why are there capital letters in openSUSE packages?

Tags: opensuse

In Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora, the package is called `python3-sphinx`. On openSUSE, the package is called `python3-Sphinx`. Same with `python3-prettytable` versus `python3-PrettyTable`. I find those capital letters hard to remember and hard to get right. Why are they in the names of the packages?

Comment: Poor choices? Lack of standards? Debian Policy explicitly says only lower case letters should be used. I don't think SUSE has an equivalent. I doubt this question has a real answer, though you could try asking SUSE. Better, suggest they make a policy to stick to lower case letters. There are software projects (R comes to mind) that also engage in this unfortunate practice.

Comment: Actually there are [Packaging guidelines](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Package_naming_guidelines). These allow upper case characters in package names. `Sphinx` seems to be the official project name. `Sphinx` is also used in `pip`. So this seems to be a legit package name.

Answer (score 4):

From the openSUSE [Package naming guidelines - Case Sensitivity](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Package_naming_guidelines#Case_Sensitivity):

> In openSUSE packaging, the maintainer should use his/her best
>   judgement when considering how to name the package. While case
>   sensitivity is not a mandatory requirement, case should only be used
>   where necessary. Keep in mind to respect the wishes of the upstream
>   maintainers. **If they refer to their application as "ORBit", you should
>   use "ORBit" as the package name, and not "orbit".** However, if they do
>   not express any preference of case, you should default to lowercase
>   naming.

in contrast to Fedora's [Naming Guidelines - General Naming](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#General_Naming)

> When naming a package you can take some cues from the name of the
>   upstream tarball, project name from which this software came, and what
>   has been used for this package by other distributions/packagers in the
>   past. Do not just blindly follow those examples, however, as package
>   names should strive to be consistent within Fedora more than
>   consistent between distros. **You should generally use lowercase** and
>   turn underscores into dashes unless there's a compelling reason to
>   follow a different upstream convention.